# How to append html tag <br> after div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to append a `<br>` after a `<div>`.

**My code**

```
function generatescene() {
    for (i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
        $('#fightarea').append('<div class=\'block block' + i + '\'><img src=block.png></div>');
        if (i % 5) { } else {
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                console.log('.block' + i + ' img');
                $('.block' + i).after('<br>');
            }
        }
    }
    $('.block').wrapAll('<div class=\'scene\'></div>');
}
```

**I have this result**

```
<div>
  <div class="scene">
    <div class="block block1"><img src="block.png"></div>
    <div class="block block2"><img src="block.png"></div>
    <div class="block block3"><img src="block.png"></div>
    <div class="block block4"><img src="block.png"></div>
    <div class="block block5"><img src="block.png"></div>
    <div class="block block6"><img src="block.png"></div>
    <div class="block block7"><img src="block.png"></div>
    <div class="block block8"><img src="block.png"></div>
    <div class="block block9"><img src="block.png"></div>
    <div class="block block10"><img src="block.png"></div>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

The `<br>` append after the `div.scene` but I want the `<br>` append after the `"div.block" + i`.

Comment: I would respectfully suggest that those line breaks aren't needed anyway. You shouldn't use elements for spacing. Just put a style rule on `.block`, or add a new class for spacing and give it a margin.

Comment: Remove the `.wrapAll` and it does what you're expecting

Comment: [wrapAll()](https://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) *The structure will be wrapped around all of the elements in the set of matched elements, **as a single group**.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
$('.block').wrapAll('<div class=\'scene\'></div>');
```

which, as stated in the jquery [wrapAll](https://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) doc does:

> The structure will be wrapped around all of the elements in the set of matched elements, as a single group.

so it takes all the `.block` elements that are siblings and creates a single group, thus moving your `<br/>`s to *outside* the `.scene` div.

```js
function generatescene() {
    for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        $('#fightarea').append('<div class=\'block block' + i + '\'><img src=block.png></div>');
        if (i % 5) { } else {
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                console.log('.block' + i + ' img');
                $('.block' + i).after('<br>');
            }
        }
    }
    //$('.block').wrapAll('<div class=\'scene\'></div>');
}
generatescene();

$("#btn").click(function() {
    $('.block').wrapAll('<div class=\'scene\'></div>');
});
```

```css
.block { float:left; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">wrap all </button>
<hr/>
<div id='fightarea'>
</div>
```

---

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve, perhaps adding the `.scene` div first and then inserting the blocks inside that?

```js
function generatescene() {
    var scene = $('<div class=\'scene\'></div>').appendTo("#fightarea");
    for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        scene.append('<div class=\'block block' + i + '\'><img src=block.png></div>');
        if (i % 5) { } else {
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                console.log('.block' + i + ' img');
                $('.block' + i).after('<br>');
            }
        }
    }
    
}
generatescene();
```

```css
.block { float:left; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='fightarea'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
 $('.block' + i).append('<br>');
```

instead of

```
 $('.block' + i).after('<br>');
```

### Explanation:

When you are using .after() you put the element after the element

Ex.

```
$('.a').after($('.c'));
```

will result in

```
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>b</div>
</div>
<div class='c'>c</div>
```

but on the other hand when using .append()

```
$('.a').append($('.c'));
```

to

```
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>b</div>
  <div class='c'>c</div>
</div>
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: @freedomn-m Ohhh...I thought they wanted to add a child. Should I delete my answer? Or can you edit it and I will approve?

Comment: @freedomn-m I 100% agree with you, it completely depends on the OP. Ultimately, both of our answers work!

Comment: Apologies I deleted the comments when I reread that the question does include *but I want the `<br>` append after the "div.block" + i* - this answer works to put the div inside the block.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
function generatescene() {
  for (i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    var sthtm ='<div class=\'block block' + i + '\'><img src=block.png></div>';
    if(i==0) shtm ='<div class=\'scene\'>'+shtm;
    if ((i % 5) == 0) {
      sthtm +='<br>';
      console.log('.block' + i + ' img');
    }
    if(i==100) shtm +='</div>';
    $('#fightarea').append(sthtm);
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding a single html might make it (a tiny tiny bit) more efficient, but still has the `.wrapAll` issue - did you try your code?  https://jsfiddle.net/pgyrxckL/